# How can I run a bash script (which downloads a file) in Java?

Tags: java, bash, download, runtime

Running in Mac OS X Lion, I need to retrieve a file from a remote server using a script in the command line. The command I'm trying to use in code is "bash /my/path/here/myscript" and I already run another process from the command line (atos) using the code below.

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

But while debugging, the program continues without error, yet the script does appear to have actually run. Furthermore, there should be a pause of several seconds while the script retrieves the file, yet my program continues to execute immediately. The script itself works as intended when run from the terminal. I'm a little stumped on how to get this to work, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the question? What do you mean by "while the program continues, it does appear to have actually run"? That is hard to understand. Downloading a file is going to be an asynchronous operation.

Comment: @jahroy: The bash script, the cmd seems not to have run.

Comment: Ok... You might want to edit your question so it doesn't state the OPPOSITE of what is actually happening.  What steps have you taken to debug why it does not run? You provide us no code, no error messages, no explanation... You will probably have to play around quite a bit to get your bash script to run. What platform are you on? Linux, Unix, Mac, Cygwin, etc...?

Comment: How does your download command look like? How do you observe, that it didn't run. And: There are pretty little symbols above the edit box. Try them out! Use them! Feel welcome.

Comment: are you just doing an ftp to some remote server?

Comment: I've attempted to clarify a few things, sorry about that. But yes, I am doing an ftp to a remote server and grabbing some file I need for my program to continue execution correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work with the following code -

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
proc.waitFor();

while (in.ready()) {
    System.out.println(in.readLine());
}
```

The other thing that was an issue is that the script would download to the current working directory rather than the location of the script itself (as intended). So the script would run correctly while my program would continue to fail to find the downloaded file. Hope this helps.